# Read data from Jad file

Tags: blackberry

I'm working on blackberry device.
 want to save the server url in jad file and read this URL programtically in my application.
how do i do this in blackberry

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to check out CodeModuleGroup.  Here's the JavaDocs on it:

[CodeModuleGroup Documentation](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/CodeModuleGroup.html)

Also, here's a link from the BlackBerry forums on reading attributes from the JAD.

[How To - Programmatically read the attributes of a JAD file](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800708/800646/How_To_-_Programmatically_read_the_attributes_of_a_JAD_file.html?nodeid=1382517&vernum=0)